# Error in chatterbot from chatterbot.corpus.english

Tags: path, training-data, chatterbot

I am new to python, and wont to learn more. getting fee wet with a simple chatbot.
running to error when Debugging the program.

```
import time
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
time.clock = time.time


chatbot = ChatBot('Bob') <------ Here (If i didn't use import time module ('time' has no attribute 'clock')error is thrown) 

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)


trainer.train(
   chatterbot.corpus.english'<----- Here i get (Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'collections' has no attribute 'Hashable') 
)

bot = ChatBot(
    'Bob',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
)

bot = ChatBot(
    'Bob',  
    logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'],
)

response = bot.get_response('Greetings.')

print("Bot Response:", response)

name=input("Enter Your Name: ")
print("Welcome to the Bot Service! Let me know how can I help you?")
while True:
    request=input(name+':')
    if request=='Bye' or request =='bye':
        print('Bot: Bye')
        break
    else:
        response=bot.get_response(request)
        print('Bot:',response)
```

So far i trying to create my own corpus file on my computer. But not sure if it will throw the same error or if this is an error that has to do with incompatibility issues. New here any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force compatibility, as a workaround, by adding the following lines:

For error: ***'time' has no attribute 'clock'***

```
import time

time.clock = time.time
```

For error: ***module 'collections' has no attribute 'Hashable'***

```
import collections.abc

collections.Hashable = collections.abc.Hashable
```

Should required to have installed the versions compatible with Python 3.10 as follows:

```
pip install -U PyYaml==3.12
pip install time
```